# Web Server Controls Code Behind doesn't see my dataset configuration

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have 2 WebServer Controls

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server"ClientIDMode="Static"MaxtLength="30"Width="35px"CssClass="labeltext"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:DropDownList ID ="ddlDropDown" runat ="server" CssClass="text">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="U">someValue1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Y">someValue2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="N">someValue3</asp:ListItem>                 
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

There are no Errors on my aspx Page. I have configured my datasets to read the 2 new columns ( I even double checked the designer file for the dsd and see both new columns). I have cleaned and rebuilt my solution but my code behind (.vb) only see the dropdown and not the Text Box,

Comment: Can you show the code where you attempt to access the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, somehow the dataset got out of sync. I think it was because I tried to copy and paste a property in my aspx. I undid all my changes and re applied them again with no issue.